# Neo4j : Weakly Connected Component (WCC), keep big network only in a memory graph

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm

I ran Neo4J WCC algorithm to see how connected is my data.

My data looks like this:

[image]

I did this to project a graph :

```
load_graph = """ CALL gds.graph.create('lpa_test_2','*','APPEARS_IN');"""
run_query(load_graph)
```

I have the following result :

[image]

I would like to keep the big network (size 1670) in a memory graph.

I tried this :

```
CALL gds.graph.create.cypher(
'myGraph_14',
'MATCH (n) WHERE n.familyComponent = 0 RETURN id(n) as id',
'MATCH (a:Article)<-[:APPEARS_IN]-(b:keyword)-[:APPEARS_IN]->(c:Article) RETURN id(a) AS source, id(c) AS target')
YIELD graphName, nodeCount, relationshipCount, createMillis;
```

I have all the nodes but not the relationships :

[image]

What can I do to have all the relationships in the big network ?
Knowing that the database has two types of nodes and one relationship type.

Comment: The relationship query found no matches, maybe check if there are any typos?

Comment: When I try WCC in write mode and try to see 'relationshipPropertiesWritten' it says **CypherSyntaxError: Unknown procedure output: relationshipPropertiesWritten**.

I tried this:


`CALL gds.wcc.write('my-graph', 
    {writeProperty:'familyComponent'})
    YIELD componentCount, nodePropertiesWritten,relationshipPropertiesWritten;`

Comment: Maybe at the beginning when I created the graph I have no relationship. I don't know where I made the mistake.

I also tried to change nodes name in uppercase and I have the following error:

ClientError: Failed to invoke procedure `gds.graph.create.cypher`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load relationship with unknown source-node id 2368.

Comment: As for the second issue: add the following parameter -> validateRelationships:false

Comment: Thank you very much it works.